# is suprressing warnings for generic types safe when the object is immutable?

Tags: java, generics

I have a simple class that wraps an unmodifiable list (it is used as a context for a query):

```
public class Context<T extends Node> implements Iterable<T> {

    private final List<T> m_nodes;
    
    Context(List<T> nodes) {
        m_nodes = Collections.unmodifiableList(nodes);
    }
    
    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return m_nodes.iterator();
    }

    public int indexOf(T node) {
        return m_nodes.indexOf(node);
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return m_nodes.isEmpty();
    }

    // context are always sorted by pre value
    public boolean containsAll(FDMContext<T> other) {
        Iterator<T> oit = other.iterator();
        Iterator<T> sit = iterator();
        int c = 0;

        while( oit.hasNext()) {
            T o = oit.next();
            while( sit.hasNext()) {
                T s = sit.next();
                if( s.getPre() == o.getPre()) {
                    c++;
                    break;
                }
           }
        }
        return c == other.size();
    }
    
    public int size() {
        return m_nodes.size();
    }
    
    public List<T> getNodes() {
        return m_nodes;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return m_nodes.toString();
   }

}
```

The `Node` class has a `Value` subclass.  I don't think the details of the Node and Value class are important, except that they share a common `getPre()` method defining a unique node identifier.

If there is a method that expects an `Context<Value>` parameter but I have an `Context<Node>` instance as a result of a query *where I am certain it only contains `Value` instances*, is it safe to suppress warnings?

e.g.

```
static Entry makeEntry(Event event, Group head, Group tail, Context<Value> values) { 
    /* code */
}

...

Context<Node> ctx = query(anotherCtx,somePath);   // the result ctx contains only Value objects.  The query method returns a Context(Node) object

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
Entry ret = makeEntry( this, headGrp, tailGrp, (Context)tail);
```

I could create a new context of type `Context<Value>`, but I'd rather avoid the copy if possible.

Comment: Why are you declaring `ctx` as `FDMContext<Node>` if you know it is of type `FDMContext<Value>`?

Comment: Sorry the code is a little unclear, the ctx variable is the result of a query method call that always returns an Context<Node> result

Comment: I think a more complete example would help.

Comment: How do you know that your call of `query` will always return only a `Context` containing instances of `Value`?

Comment: @cyberbrain it is in a particular code path where i know the `Context` will consist of `Value` instances, but in general search results can contain any type of `Node`.

Comment: well, it depends a bit on what you mean with "safe". Compiler guarantees that no ClassCastException will occur with generic collections at runtime if no warning was emitted at compile time, but only until you use that `@SuppressWarnings`. If that's safe enough for you, you're fine. Otherwise we would need to know more details about that query that is producing the "wrongly" typed result. To me it looks as if the real question is "does this query always return only Value elements?".